# file_get_contents() почему возвращает страницу не целиком?

Tags: php

Использую `file_get_contents()` для чтения объемного файла, но в результате получаю не всю страницу целиком. Предполагаю, что где-то в настройках сервера стоит ограничение. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пофиксить? Спасибо!

Comment: Странно, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php у функции есть параметр length, но по умолчанию он не задан и считывается всё

Comment: А что получаете? Что значит «не всю страницу целиком»?

Comment: Содержимое страницы обрезается. P.S объем файла достаточно большой.

Comment: файл локальный или remote?

Comment: Используйте fopen + curl

Comment: Файл локальный, cURL тоже обрезает, fopen тоже